# What purpose of MOVZX EAX,AX after MOVZX EAX, WORD PTR [RBP+ADDR.SA_DATA]?

Tags: ida, assembly, x86

I thought it was strange when I was looking at the code below. The first instruction clearly has completed the task of data transfer and expansion into 16 bits. Why is there a "mov Eax,ax" in the assembly code?

```
    movzx   eax, word ptr [rbp+addr.sa_data]
    movzx   eax, ax
    mov     edi, eax
    call    _htons
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously the `movzx eax, ax` is useless.
I would say this is unoptimized code, this C code could reproduce the same generated code.

```
#include <stdint.h>

void f(uint16_t v)
{
}

struct S
{
        uint16_t a;
};

int main(void)
{
        struct S s;
        s.a = 0x1122;
        f(s.a);
        return 0;
}
```

Compiling with gcc without optimization options, the code is:

```
1134:       0f b7 45 fe             movzx  eax,WORD PTR [rbp-0x2]
1138:       0f b7 c0                movzx  eax,ax
113b:       89 c7                   mov    edi,eax
113d:       e8 d7 ff ff ff          call   1119 <f>
```

Note, I wasn't able to produce the same result neither with clang or vc++.
Besides, it only happens when the value is read from a structure.

Comment: I think it's because I took the data from the addr structure and produced this code. Thank you for your answer.